# Sound output device changed after resume from suspend/restart in 17.10

Tags: sound, suspend, 17.10, settings

After resuming my computer from suspend/restarting it the sound output is allways changed to another sound output device in list found in the sound settings after the upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10. To be able to use the mute/volume up/volume down keys I have to change the output device every single time I resume the computer.

Is there a solution/workaround for this?