# I can't select the default sound output via settings

Tags: gnome, 17.10, system-settings

I've selected a sound output via settings in Gnome on Ubuntu 17.10 several times now, but it keeps changing back to another output (after restarting). It seems like there is no way from the settings GUI to keep a device selected (i.e., as a default).

This is similar to: [Sound output device changed after resume from suspend/restart in 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/975354/724441).

So while obviously it would be good to have this feature in the GUI, is there another way to set this?